# Dependency Management in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I referred to [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

I am working with Spring Tool Suite (STS). When I created my first 'Spring Legacy Project' in STS, the following POM file was already present :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBoot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Now, as I understand Spring Boot, it manages all the addition of the required  dependencies for me. In [the link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) that I referred, I was told to add the following content to my project, as soon as I create it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**My question is,** does the above content of the Spring Boot pom file have to be added **along with** the existing content, or should I cut the old content and paste this new one?? If Spring Boot is going to manage my dependencies for me, the existing dependencies shouldn't be there, right??

Thanks in advance.

Spring Config

```
package config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

public class SpringConfig {

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry reg)
    {
        reg.addResourceHandler("/resources/**/").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    }

    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return vr;
    }

}
```

WebAppInit

```
package config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Controller

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

Application(Main)

```
package hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
         System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

         String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
          Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }
    }

}
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>

        Hello
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, your existing POM does not contain any dependencies that are not managed by Spring so you should just replace the old POM with the new, Spring Boot-managed one.

Generally, the best way to go forward would be to start from your existing POM and remove managed dependencies one by one.

Comment: And how should I run this application? As a Java Application? Or, since there is a view, I should run it on a server - 'Run On Server' ?

Comment: Being a SpringBoot Application, If the application will look for the main method, should it be run as a Java application?

Comment: That's really up to you - Spring Boot allows you to choose. But by default, you run Spring Boot applications via the main method. You can take a look at the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html) for more details.

Comment: I am getting a 404 error when I run my application as 'Run On Server'. What may have gone wrong?

Comment: That's probably because you haven't modified your configuration properly. Spring Boot allows you to choose how to run the application but it doesn't automatically support deployments to server. Take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html and https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: I'm on my cell, I probably won't be able to give it a try before tomorrow; until then, could you push your code to GitHub? It'd be easier to copy and run. But what I can tell you right now is that you're using a `@RestController` so even if your configuration was ok you wouldn't be able to display the index page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122070/discussion-between-nishil-and-milos-milivojevic).